# How to Split a deck of cards in half?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a really simple game of war. User and computer draws 1 card per turn, they either win, tie, or lose. Game is over when cards are out. I have 4 classes. My war class I was mostly just testing out if things were working for the deck. What I need to do is split the deck in half so each player draws 1 card each turn (A total of 26 by the end of the game) and I don't know how to do that. I'm guessing I need a for loop, but other than that I don't know how I would give each player a card. Ignore the user input in Class War, like I said, I was just testing things out. I have 3 classes displayed here, my last one is a JApplet which isn't need here so I haven't included it.

**EDIT**: Thanks for the help guys. I have one last problem and then I should be good. I want to display Card.toString inside my JApplet class but when I call Card card = new Card(); it refuses to work. I'm guessing this is because of the constructor. How would I go about getting that toString to display, or bypass the constructor.

**Edit**: Figure everything out, Thanks for the help guys.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class Card {
    private int suit, number;
    String [] suits = {"Heart" , "Diamond" , "Spade" , "Club"}; //suits
    String [] numbers = { "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , "10" ,
    "Jack" , "Queen" , "King" , "Ace" }; //card values
    String card = "";

     public Card(int suits, int numbers)
        {
            suit = suits; 
            number = numbers;
        }
      public String toString() //displays card suit/value
        {
            String finalCard = numbers[number] + " of " + suits[suit];
            return finalCard;
        }
    }



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class FullDeck {
    private ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();//card array list

        public FullDeck()
        {   
            for(int a =0; a<=3; a++) //loops through suits
            {
                for(int b =0; b<=12;b++) //loops through values
                {
                    cards.add(new Card(a,b)); //creates adds cards to list
                }

            }

        }

        public Card drawRandomCard()
        {
            Random generator = new Random(); //picks random card
            int index = generator.nextInt(cards.size());
            return cards.remove(index); //removes card from list
        }



        public String toString()
        {
            String result = "Cards remaining in deck: " + cards; //not currently used
            return result;
        }    
    }

import java.util.Scanner;

public class War {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Card C;
        FullDeck hand1 = new FullDeck();
        FullDeck hand2 = new FullDeck();

        System.out.println("Enter number of cards to be dealt: ");
        int numberCards = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Cards drawn: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberCards; i++) {
          C = hand1.drawRandomCard();
          System.out.println(C.toString());
        }
    }
        }
```

Comment: Provide each player with a deck, each made with half the original deck  ^^

Comment: easy way would be to give both players a full deck as you have done, and whenever one card is drawn, remove that card from both decks...

Comment: Why do you need to split the deck, if when you call `drawRandomCard()` it removes the card from the deck? If the player and the computer call `drawRandomCard()` in turn, it will automatically happen that each will get 26 cards in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two `ArrayList<Card>`s, then make a `for` loop that goes through 52 times.

```
for(int i=0;i<52;i++){
    Card tempCard = hand1.getCards().remove(hand1.getCards().indexOf(hand1.drawRandomCard()));
    if(i%2 == 1){
        firstPlayersCards.add(tempCard);
    }else{
        secondPlayersCards.add(tempCard);
    }
}
```

Make sure to add a `getCards()` method in `FullDeck` which just returns `cards`.

And this way all of the cards are randomized in each player's hands, so you can just get them in order.

Edit: though, the *simplest* solution is what Daniel Gabriel said and to just call `drawRandomCard()` twice in a row.

Comment: `i < 52`?  Would be better if you were checking the length of the array you're getting indexes into.

Comment: Why? I don't care about the length of the array because I know its size. I mean if it was an irregular deck of cards then yeah, you're right, but that's pretty superfluous for this scenario.

Comment: Here's why checking the array length is better.  What happens if I do decide to modify how the deck is constructed?  Or perhaps I want to do other things with my game, whatever.  The more places I hard-code `52` in, the more places I have to go and fix if I decide to make a change in deck size, for whatever reason.  Using the size of the array means the results are identical and the method is more flexible.  Every time you change a piece of code, you have to retest it... so try to write your code in a manner that decreases the odds of ever having to rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

It'd make sense to rename your `FullDeck` class to just `Deck`...

Then, include a constructor for `Deck` that takes an `ArrayList` as a parameter.  Include a method for `Deck` that returns a `Deck` object and is called something like `splitDeck`.

Internally, the `splitDeck` takes half the cards in `Deck`, removes them from `cards` on that object, and adds them to a new, temporary `ArrayList`.  Then, it creates and returns an a deck object built using this temporary `ArrayList`.

---

```
public Deck(ArrayList<Card> deck) {
    cards = deck;
}

public Deck splitDeck() {
    ArrayList<Card> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = cards.length() - 1; i >= cards.length()/2; --i) {
        temp.add(cards.get(i));
        cards.remove(i);
    }
    return new Deck(temp);
}
```

Now the `Deck` object on which you called the method contains half a deck, and the `Deck` object returned contains the other half.

---

Assuming you rename the class to `Deck` (just because it'd make more sense) and kept the same default constructor:

```
Deck playerOneDeck = new Deck();
// playerOne now has a full deck of cards

Deck playerTwoDeck = playerOneDeck.splitDeck();
// playerOne and playerTwo now each have half of playerOne's original full deck
```